# How to select based on a partial string match in Mathematica

Tags: string, wolfram-mathematica

Say I have a matrix that looks something like this:

```
{{foobar, 77},{faabar, 81},{foobur, 22},{faabaa, 8},
{faabian, 88},{foobar, 27}, {fiijii, 52}}
```

and a list like this:

```
{foo, faa}
```

Now I would like to add up the numbers for each line in the matrix based on the partial match of the strings in the list so that I end up with this:

```
{{foo, 126},{faa, 177}}
```

I assume I need to map a Select command, but I am not quite sure how to do that and match only the partial string. Can anybody help me? Now my real matrix is around 1.5 million lines so something that isn't too slow would be of added value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is yet another approach.  It is reasonably fast, and also concise.

```
data =
 {{"foobar", 77},
  {"faabar", 81},
  {"foobur", 22},
  {"faabaa", 8},
  {"faabian", 88},
  {"foobar", 27},
  {"fiijii", 52}};

match = {"foo", "faa"};

f = {#2, Tr @ Pick[#[[All, 2]], StringMatchQ[#[[All, 1]], #2 <> "*"]]} &;

f[data, #]& /@ match
```

```
{{"foo", 126}, {"faa", 177}}
```

---

You can use ruebenko's pre-processing for greater speed.
This is about twice as fast as his method on my system:

```
{str, vals} = Transpose[data];
vals = Developer`ToPackedArray[vals];

f2 = {#, Tr @ Pick[vals, StringMatchQ[str, "*" <> # <> "*"]]} &;

f2 /@ match
```

Notice that in this version I test substrings that are not at the beginning, to match ruebenko's output.  If you want to only match at the beginning of strings, which is what I assumed in the first function, it will be faster still.

Comment: I like it. Fast, flexible and does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a starting point:

```
data={{"foobar",77},{"faabar",81},{"foobur",22},{"faabaa",8},{"faabian",88},{"foobar",27},{"fiijii",52}};

{str,vals}=Transpose[data];
vals=Developer`ToPackedArray[vals];
findValPos[str_List,strPat_String]:=
    Flatten[Developer`ToPackedArray[
         Position[StringPosition[str,strPat],Except[{}],{1},Heads->False]]]

Total[vals[[findValPos[str,"faa"]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

make data

```
mat = {{"foobar", 77},
   {"faabar", 81},
   {"foobur", 22},
   {"faabaa", 8},
   {"faabian", 88},
   {"foobar", 27},
   {"fiijii", 52}};
lst = {"foo", "faa"};
```

now select

```
r1 = Select[mat, StringMatchQ[lst[[1]], StringTake[#[[1]], 3]] &];
r2 = Select[mat, StringMatchQ[lst[[2]], StringTake[#[[1]], 3]] &];
{{lst[[1]], Total@r1[[All, 2]]}, {lst[[2]], Total@r2[[All, 2]]}}
```

gives

```
{{"foo", 126}, {"faa", 177}}
```

I'll try to make it more functional/general if I can...

**edit(1)**

This below makes it more general. (using same data as above):

```
foo[mat_, lst_] := Select[mat, StringMatchQ[lst, StringTake[#[[1]], 3]] &]
r = Map[foo[mat, #] &, lst];
MapThread[ {#1, Total[#2[[All, 2]]]} &, {lst, r}]
```

gives

```
{{"foo", 126}, {"faa", 177}}
```

So now same code above will work if lst was changed to 3 items instead of 2:

```
lst = {"foo", "faa", "fii"};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
list = {{"foobar", 77}, {"faabar", 81}, {"foobur", 22}, {"faabaa", 
    8}, {"faabian", 88}, {"foobar", 27}, {"fiijii", 52}};

t = StringTake[#[[1]], 3] &;

{t[#[[1]]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ SplitBy[SortBy[list, t], t]

{{"faa", 177}, {"fii", 52}, {"foo", 126}}
```

I am sure I have read a post, maybe here, in which someone described a function that effectively combined sorting and splitting but I cannot remember it. Maybe someone else can add a comment if they know of it.

**Edit**

ok must be bedtime -- how could I forget `Gatherby`

```
{t[#[[1]]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ GatherBy[list, t]

{{"foo", 126}, {"faa", 177}, {"fii", 52}}
```

Note that for a dummy list of 1.4 million pairs this took a couple of seconds so not exactly a super fast method.

Comment: Just  noticed after posting an answer based on `GatherBy`  that your requested a comment and that you remembered it before bedtime. Deleting my answer.. For a minor generalization you can make `t` take a parameter `t[k_]=StringTake[@[[1]],k]%`. (+1)